# Understanding a step in Baire Category Theorem

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

I have a (probably stupid) question about the Baire Category Theorem. I am looking at the statement that says that in a complete metric space, the intersection of countable many dense open sets is dense in the metric space.
Assume that we have the countable collection of dense open sets $\{U_n\}$ in a complete metric space $X$, and let $x \in X, \epsilon>0$. Since $U_1$ is dense in $X$, there is $y_1\in U_1$ with $d(x,y_1)<\epsilon$. Also, as $U_1$ is open, there is $r_1>0$ with $B(y_1;r_1)\subset U_1$. **Then, we can arrange $r_1<1$ such that  $\overline{B(y_1;r_1)} \subset U_1\cap B(x;\epsilon)$.**
Now my question is why we can arrange that the closure will be contained in each of them? I think intuitively it sounds correct, but I didn't succeed to prove it rigorously. Can you please help me here?

Comment: The correct statement is that the intersection of countably many dense open subsets is **dense**, not open. Eg the irrational numbers are not open in the reals but are of that form.

Comment: Follow-up to the above comment. It seems that you made a typo, saying "open" when you meant to say"dense". If so, it would be better if you edited your Q before you get any negative comments.

Comment: Since the intersection of a non-empty finite family of dense open sets is also dense and open,  the proof is a little easier if we begin by letting $V_n=\cap_{j\leq n}U_j,$ since $V_{n+1}\subset V_n.$ We have $\cap_{n\in \Bbb N}V_n=\cap_{n\in \Bbb N}U_n,$ and each $V_n$ is dense & open.

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed it. Corrected it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$d(x, y_1) < \varepsilon$ actually means $y_1 \in B(x; \varepsilon)$. Also $y_1 \in U_1$ by construction.

Hence $y_1 \in U_1 \cap B(x;\varepsilon)$. Now, since $U_1 \cap B(x;\varepsilon)$ is an open neighbourhood of $y_1$, there exists $r < 1$ such that $B(y_1, r) \subseteq U_1 \cap B(x;\varepsilon)$. Now define $r_1 = \frac{r}2$ and notice

$$\overline{B(y_1, r_1)} = \overline{B\left(y_1, \frac{r}2\right)} \subseteq B(y_1, r) \subseteq U_1 \cap B(x;\varepsilon)$$